# PhpMyAdmin (alternative?) for MariaDB Unix Socket

Tags: unix, phpmyadmin, mariadb

I am running Mariadb v10.1.37 which uses Unix sockets to login, is there a way to setup Phpmyadmin to sign in with the Unix socket? Or are there any alternative guis for debian 9 stretch that allows basic database management and Unix socket authentication?

Comment: You need to configure phpmyadmin to use the unix socket instead of localhost

Comment: Could you tell me in which file I have to look for that?

Comment: Nope, cuz i don't know, however u can find it using "grep -r localhost <phpmyadmin path>"

Comment: Most probably it will be a config.php

Comment: After running `sudo dpkg-reconfigure phpmyadmin` I got a lot more options, including unix socket auth!

Comment: Awesome, add it as an answer

Answer (score 1):

So for some reason after running `sudo dpkg-reconfigure phpmyadmin` you get a lot more options, like the option to sign in using UNIX sockets and you also get the option to create a new user and password, after doing that I just had to grant all permissions to the new user